# Subtract two vectors of different size in C++

Tags: c++, vector, comparison, subtraction

I have two vectors: one populated with a stride of 5, so it's size can be `5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30 ... 5n`.
And the other is populated with a stride of 6, so it's size is `6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36 ... 6n`
I'd like to subtract these two vectors as they were the same size. Since they both hold coordinates of a curve I thought I might subtract the middle two elements in the second vector so something like this:

```
// The numbers are indexes
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) =
(0, 1, 3 - 2, 4, 5)
```

The new size is 5. But it's not as easy on a general case when using a for loop to maintain and compare them both. The comparison should be something like this:

```
// The numbers are indexes
vector<int> v1 = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
vector<int> v2 = (0, 1, 3 - 2, 4, 5);
vector<int> v3 = v1 - v2
```

Example:

```
// Actual numbers
vector<int> v1 = (110, 210, 310, 410, 510, 610, 710, 810, 910, 1010);
vector<int> v2 = (120, 220, 320, 420, 520, 620, 720, 820, 920, 1020, 1120, 1220);
vector<int> v3 = v1 - v2; // error - vectors different size

// so we try to fix it
v2 = (120, 220, (420 - 320), 520, 620, 720, 820, (920 - 1020), 1120, 1220);
v2 = (220, 100, 520, 620, 720, 820, 100, 1120, 1220); // resized vector in the desired fasion

v3 = v1 - v2; // still not ok - the vector is of the size 9.
```

Works just fine for the example of `1n` but goes per shape when `n > 1`. How to do it, the same way, when the size of both vectors changes but they are always going to be populated the same number of times `n`? These vectors represent lines. I want to know the distances between each individual points in both vectors: so how far is the point `v1[0]` from the point `v2[0]` ect.

Comment: Your example doesn't show any comparison. What exactly are you trying to compare?

Comment: You're right. My bad. Already changed the title.

Comment: Slow down. Forget about vectors; forget about loops; forget about writing code. Explain (to yourself first, then to others if necessary) exactly what it means to compare two of these collections of indices. Once you know what it is that you're trying to do, you can figure out how to write the code.

Comment: What are the rules of subtracting two elements from one or one from two? Do you add the two elements together and make it one number before performing subtraction?  Do you calculate the average? Your question is super vague.

Comment: @PeteBecker I've added an example. Hope it makes it clearer of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @KillzoneKid could you please have a look now with the example?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please try to clarify and see the [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) reference.

Comment: Your example doesn't help. What it shows is that when you want to subtract a vector with 5 elements from a vector with 6 elements, you combine the middle two elements of the 6-element vector to get a 5-element vector, and use that for the subtraction. That's easy to do. But it doesn't make it at all clear what it is that you want in other cases. As I said, don't be in such a hurry to write code. Think about what you **mean** by subtracting two collections that have different sizes.

Comment: @PeteBecker it's easy to do when you have an example like this and maybe easy enough to do in a general case when the size changes but that's what I'm after. How to do it, the same way, when the size changes? These vectors represent lines. I want to know the distances between each individual points in both vectors: so how far is the point v1[0] from the point v2[0] ect.

Comment: You have only told us what you want to do if v1 is 5 elements and v2 is 6 elements, and then asked you would do that in the general case.  That isn't enough information.

Think about it this way. I tell you that I am trying to define an operator `+` such that for odd numbers `a` and `b`, `a + b = 2a+b` and I ask you, for my operator, what do I do if either `a` or `b` are not odd? That isn't for you to decide.

You have to specify what behavior you want in general in order for you to even be able to begin figuring out how to implement it.

Comment: @GarrettGutierrez Well that's what I'm struggling with. If I knew the principle behind the general case it wouldn't be a problem to implement. I just fail to see one. Does this make sense?

Comment: @CarrotCake If you don't know the principle behind how you want the operator to behave, then why bother implementing the operator? You should actually start with a problem: given this input I want this output, and then the rest is meant to achieve that, rather than starting with the operator and working towards how it should behave.

Comment: The `3-2` thing makes little sense to me. Why on earth would you subtract? Averaging (`(3+2)/2`) would be more intuitive. Still, the result won't make much sense.